# curl post array data

Tags: arrays, json, curl, post

My JSON Block

```
{

  "type": "abcd",

  "data": {

    "id": [

      "efgh"

    ],

    "model": "ijkl"

  }
```

I tried updating 'type' using the following curl post, but it doesn't like it.

```
curl -X PUT  -d  '{"id":["ABCD"]}'
```

Comment: depends on your backend. Do you have documentation of this API endpoint ?

Comment: OK. I went through api documentation. Its PATCH, instead of a PUT.